# How to write wait in the method in Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, selenium-chromedriver

This method of loading the page of the navigation link, it takes time to test committed. My test falls when it checks the page is loaded with the correct url. I tried to write:

```
waitForElementToBeDisplayed(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+submenus[i]+"')]")), 500);

Thread.sleep(2000);
```

**This is my code:**

```
public void showNavigationLinks(){
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        String[] submenus = {"Accessories", "iMacs", "iPads" , "iPhones" , "iPods" , "MacBook"};   

        for(int i=0;i<submenus.length;i++)
        {
            waitForElementToBeDisplayed(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Product Category')]")), 500);
            WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Product Category')]"));

            action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+submenus[i]+"')]"))).click().build().perform();

            //Checking correct URL
            waitForElementToBeDisplayed(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'"+submenus[i]+"')]")), 500);
            Assert.assertTrue("checking if URL contains: " + submenus[i],
                    driver.getCurrentUrl().toLowerCase().contains(submenus[i].toLowerCase()));
        }
}
```

**This is my error:**

> java.lang.AssertionError: checking if URL contains: iMacs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the expected URL, you can use a dynamic wait instead of a "dumb" sleep. This would wait for the URL for up to 1 minute and proceed as soon as it is found (which might be far less than 1 minute, polling twice a second):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(submenus[i].toLowerCase()));
```

You could also use `urlToBe` (if you know the exact URL) or `urlMatches` (if you want to use a regex pattern).

Comment: Get out this error when I put you code: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for url to contain "Accessories". Current url: "http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/accessories/" (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: @DyJon In that case you should use `toLower`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is error now: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for url to contain "ipods". Current url: "http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/product-category/iphones/" (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: Nice. It shows that your code is working as expected.